# JQuery validate field number length depends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm using [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and i want change the `minlength` and `maxlength` of my field (zip code) that depends if country is equal to PT (Portugal) or not.

But in validation the result are always:

[image]

Anyone knows what is my problem?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, minimum 3(Other) or 9(PT): </label>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field"/>
<br/>
<select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
    <option value="0">-- Choose Country --</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium </option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil </option>
    <option value="ES">Spain </option>
    <option value="FR">France </option>
    <option value="NL">Dutch </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="PT">Portugal </option>       
    </select>    
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!"/>
</form>
</body>
```

**JQuery:**

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            number: {
                depends: function () {
                    return !($('select[name="country"]').val() != 'PT');
                }
            },
            minlength: {
                depends: function () {

                    var country = $('select[name="country"]').val();

                    if (country == 'PT') {
                        return 9;
                    } else {
                        return 3;
                    }
                }
            },
            maxlength: {
                depends: function () {
                    var country = $('select[name="country"]').val();
                    if (country == 'PT') {
                        return 9;
                    } else {
                        return 50;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2H9d/22/)**

Comment: please explain what is pt ? what do u want ur code to do

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird PT is the value for Portugal option. If I chose Portugal the maxlength and minlength of field go to 9, else `maxlength`=50 and `minlength`=3. My field is Zip code.

Comment: Your Question is little Complicated :) I wil hav to see properly at home :) m in office now ,wait for 2 hrs.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird you have an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer Updated.

I have made some changes, removed `depends`.

Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Y2H9d/36/

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            number: function () {
                return !($('select[name="country"]').val() != 'PT');
            },
            minlength: function () {
                var country = $('select[name="country"]').val();
                if (country == 'PT') {
                    return 9;
                } else {
                    return 3;
                }
            },
            maxlength: function () {
                var country = $('select[name="country"]').val();
                if (country == 'PT') {
                    return 9;
                } else {
                    return 50;
                }
            }
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: min and max are different from minlength and maxlength, please change in you answer.

Comment: I'm also woring on another question. So this makes confusion. Thanks for reminds me...

Comment: @JorgeB. did this answer satisfy ur requirement?If no What else is needed?

Comment: Yes @jQueryAngryBird. but I want to know if it is possible with `depends`rule.

Comment: @JorgeB. depends is not necesary .Do u knw why its used ? Its used with `required` so , it means The FIELD is required ONLY IF `depends` satisfy condition.But ur Code already has `required` rule NO MATTER WHAT , so u dont need it .   See http://blog.adrianlawley.com/jquery-validation-rules-depends/

Comment: @Siva.G , Dude u rock :) I dnt hav Upvote for today, I have STARRED the question .Tomorrow i wil upvote